# Leaflet: How to provide an offline image as a tile?

Tags: leaflet

I would like to use a `Leaflet` plug-in to provide map tiles from offline storage in the browser (`WebDB` or `FileAPI`).

How do I plug in to leaflet to feed the image object to it when it requests a tile?

A solution doesn't need to work in all browsers, Chrome will suffice.

**Background**: I have looked at various plug-in sources, and they override `getURL` and return a URL that points to an image. But I want to provide the image itself, from wherever I stored it from a previous download. Do I convert the image to a `DataURI` or an `ObjectURL`, or is there some other hook?

Answer (score 1):

Are you not able to use IndexedDB? Apparently there is some exploration being done in this area. https://github.com/mWater/offline-leaflet-map